# Remotely turn on the debian box behind a router using wakeonlan feature

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have setup a debian box behind a router. However, I am unsure how to turn it on remotely. I have heard of using wakeonlan feature, but didnot find a tutorial for it. Any help would be appreciated. I am connecting it through my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [router](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT#Features) configured to forward (or originate) the WoL packet to enable [Wake On Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Wake_on_Internet).  If you don't have DD-WRT, I would try an [online service](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/woli.aspx) to test if your router can be configured to forward the magic packet.